# Convert WKWebView to CIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I want to convert `WKWebView` or `UIWebView` to `CIImage`.
How can I do it?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.extent.size)
self.webview.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let result: CIImage = CIImage(image: 
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!, options: nil)!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I did it like this, but it does not work.I expect that the contents of `UIWebView` will be displayed in `CIImage`. Background color has been displayed.

Comment: do you want to render only the visible part of the webview or the whole content?

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi I want to render the visible part of the webview

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in 2 steps :

1. Convert `WKWebView` (having base class as `UIView`) to `UIImageView`

   ```
   extension UIImage {
       convenience init(view: UIView) {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
           view.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
           let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
           self.init(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Convert the `UIImage` received from step 1 to `CIImage`

   ```
   let ciimage = CIImage(image: image)
   ```